# Dificuldades com Arrays

Tags: c, array

Olá, Boa Tarde. Sou estudante de informática e estou tendo dificuldades com uma parte de um código, que é para a entrega de um trabalho do meu curso.

```
void criar_cliente()
{
        /// Número do dia do aniversario, será armazenado como o id do usuário.    
        int id, j = 0;
        printf ("\nInsira o dia do seu aniversario: ");
        scanf ("%d", &id);

        /// Se acaso houver um id já presente no vetor, o programa informa esse erro para o usuário.
        if (id == clientes[j])
        {
            printf ("\n***Este Cliente já existe!***\n\n");
        }

        ///Se o id não tiver presente no vetor, o programa vai criar um novo cliente.
        else
        {
            j = j + 2;
            clientes [j] = id;
            printf ("\n\nCliente Criado com Sucesso!!!");
            printf ("\n***O numero digitado será o seu identificador. Portanto não o esqueça!\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        }
}
```

Cliente[ j ] é um vetor que tem 50 posições. Esse código está dentro da função "void criar_cliente()".

Quando eu digito um valor, ex: 20, ele armazena no primeiro vetor, quando eu digito esse valor novamente, o programa diz que esse número já existe. Até aqui, o programa atende a proposta que eu quero. O problema é quando eu digito um novo valor, ex: 3, ao invés do programa pular para a próxima posição do vetor, ele atualiza o valor antigo, colocando 3 em seu lugar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse código, estou tendo a muito tempo, e até agora não encontrei uma solução. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Talvez você não tenha postado o código completo mas no trecho postado não existem as definições das variáveis utilizadas. Creio que falta código no trecho da pesquisa e também não tem explicação do motivo de pular posições no vetor.

Comment: O código inteiro é muito grande kkk, por isso coloquei somente a parte que está dando problemas. Editei o código acima inserindo as variáveis que antes esqueci de colocar. Sobre pular, é no sentido que o vetor somente atualiza os valores da posição 0, ao invés de armazenar os próximos valores nas posições seguintes.    EX: [ 0 ] = 20; [ 1 ] = 3, [ 2 ] = 8; O que acontece é que ele somente atualiza os valores do vetor 0, ao invés de colocar os valores seguintes nos próximos vetores.

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu código é na parte do if. Repare que quando a função inicia o valor de j é 0, então SEMPRE a comparação do if será:

```
if(id == clientes[0])
```

Então o valor do id só será compara do na primeira posição, caso a idade estiver em cliente[1] o programa não irá comparar com esse id.

O problema de sobre escrever é que ele sempre vai colocar o novo valor na posição j+2, como j SEMPRE será 0 então o valor sempre será 0+2:

```
0 = 0 + 2;
```

A operação acima sempre é feita e o resultado sempre será 2 e por isso seu programa sobre escreve

Uma solução simples é fazer um for para percorrer o vetor:

```
for(j = 0; j < 50; j++)
{
    if(id == cliente[j])
    {
        printf("Cliente já existe!");
    }
    else
    {
        clientes [j] = id;
        printf ("\n\nCliente Criado com Sucesso!!!");
        break;
    }
}
```

O código acima resolverá seu problema, repare que agora o if irá comparar com todas as posições dentro do cliente até achar um local onde o id digitado não exista, quando isso ocorrer então o else é ativado e o id é armazenado na posição, o break serve para sair do loop prematuramente. O código acima ainda haverá uns erros no futuro caso você exclua algum cliente, a solução para isso seria ordenar o vetor, mas isso já é assunto para outro tópico.

Comment: Mas essa estrutura me permite a criação de somente um id, ou vários como 50 descritos pelo vetor ? A verificação do if-else, irá percorrer da mesma forma todos os 50 ?

Comment: Esse for é para ser colocado na função que você mostrou, toda vez que a função for chamada ele irá ler 1 id e colocar no vetor cliente.

Comment: Entendi, Muito Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Uma dúvida, se acaso eu quisesse cadastrar mais valores, como eu deveria fazer ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi, no caso adicionar mais valores (dia do aniversário) ao cliente, certo? Basta você chamar a função toda vez quiser adicionar um novo valor, para evitar repetição de código use um loop. Mas se você quiser adicionar outros valores para o cliente (não apenas o aniversário) você teria que trabalhar com struct. Como não tenho o código completo então não sei bem como ele funciona, mas se você colocar o for que te mostrei no lugar do if na função apresentada então essa função sempre adicionará um novo id para um cliente a não ser que o vetor esteja lotado.

Comment: Ahh entendi. Muito Obrigado mesmo!!!